# How to generate multiple combinations from tables using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have few combinations of records in my table but i want to generate Multiple combinations from original table.

Records in table

| codeset | codevalue | column | system |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | 1 | null | sys1 |
| test2 | 2 | col2 | sys1 |
| test3 | 3 | col3 | sys1 |
| test3 | 4 | col4 | sys1 |
| test3 | 5 | col5 | sys1 |
| test4 | null | col6 | sys1 |
| test5 | 6 | col7 | sys2 |
| test5 | 7 | col8 | sys2 |

After applied below logic and would like to get expected output.

- Group by 'codeset'
- system name should be 'sys1'
- 'codevalue' and 'column' should be more than 1 row
- 'codevalue' and 'column' equal rows

Expected Output

| codeset | codevalue | column | system |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | 1 | null | sys1 |
| test2 | 2 | col2 | sys1 |
| test3 | 3 | col3 | sys1 |
| test3 | 3 | col4 | sys1 |
| test3 | 3 | col5 | sys1 |
| test3 | 4 | col3 | sys1 |
| test3 | 4 | col4 | sys1 |
| test3 | 4 | col5 | sys1 |
| test3 | 5 | col3 | sys1 |
| test3 | 5 | col4 | sys1 |
| test3 | 5 | col5 | sys1 |
| test4 | null | col6 | sys1 |
| test5 | 6 | col7 | sys2 |
| test5 | 7 | col8 | sys2 |

Comment: What's your logic expect result?

Comment: please provide text sample data instead of image

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). And yes, you should have explained by which rule you want to achieve the shown result. At last, you are supposed to show your own efforts. Have you been just too lazy to try anything yourself or have you forgotten to show us what you have and where you got stuck?

Comment: Sorry for not given logic and image posted.

Comment: You can Always use a SubQuery
A SubQuery is a Query within a Query. Its almost like a Select within a Select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get all possible combinations of `codevalue` and `column` for each `codeset` group when `system` has the value of `sys1`, you can use:

```sql
SELECT t1.codeset,
       t1.codevalue,
       NVL2(t2.codeset, t2."COLUMN", t1."COLUMN") AS "COLUMN",
       t1.system
FROM   table_name t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t2
       ON (
           t1.codeset = t2.codeset
       AND t1.system  = 'sys1'
       AND t2.system  = 'sys1'
       )
```

Or, as a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT codeset,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT codevalue AS codevalue,
       "COLUMN",
       system
FROM   table_name
WHERE  LEVEL <= 2
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR codeset = codeset
AND    PRIOR system  = 'sys1'
AND    system = 'sys1'
AND    PRIOR "COLUMN" != "COLUMN"
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (codeset, codevalue, "COLUMN", system) AS
SELECT 'test1', 1,    null,   'sys1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test2', 2,    'col2', 'sys1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test3', 3,    'col3', 'sys1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test3', 4,    'col4', 'sys1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test3', 5,    'col5', 'sys1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test4', null, 'col6', 'sys1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test5', 6,    'col7', 'sys2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test5', 7,    'col8', 'sys2' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | CODESET | CODEVALUE | COLUMN | SYSTEM |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | test1 | 1 | *null* | sys1 |
> | test2 | 2 | col2 | sys1 |
> | test3 | 3 | col3 | sys1 |
> | test3 | 4 | col3 | sys1 |
> | test3 | 5 | col3 | sys1 |
> | test3 | 3 | col4 | sys1 |
> | test3 | 4 | col4 | sys1 |
> | test3 | 5 | col4 | sys1 |
> | test3 | 3 | col5 | sys1 |
> | test3 | 4 | col5 | sys1 |
> | test3 | 5 | col5 | sys1 |
> | test4 | *null* | col6 | sys1 |
> | test5 | 6 | col7 | sys2 |
> | test5 | 7 | col8 | sys2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=61aaad709d691f74253ba4fd2e078511)*

Answer (score 1):

You want to self join all test3 rows. One way:

```
select codeset, codevalue, column, system
from mytable
where codeset <> 'test3'
union all
select t1.codeset, t1.codevalue, t2.column, t2.system
from (select * from mytable where codeset = 'test3') t1
cross join (select * from mytable where codeset = 'test3') t2
order by codeset, column;
```

(It is not clear from your explanation and sample data whether you want to show the system belonging to the codeset/codevalue or to the column. I took it from the column row. If you want it elsewise, change the qualifier from t2 to t1.)

Here is another, shorter approach, that you may or may nt like better:

```
select t1.codeset, t1.codevalue, t2.column, t2.system
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t2.rowid = t1.rowid or (t2.codeset = 'test3' and t1.codeset = 'test3')
order by t1.codeset, t2.column;
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I'm sorry for not given logic in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution which works. 1 Setting up and populating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE codeset (
        codeset VARCHAR(10) ,
        codevalue  INT,
        columnn  VARCHAR(10),
        systeme VARCHAR(10)
        );

INSERT INTO codeset (codeset ,codevalue ,            systeme) VALUES ('test1', 1,               'sys1');
INSERT INTO codeset (codeset ,codevalue ,  columnn,  systeme) VALUES ('test2', 2,      'col2',  'sys1');
INSERT INTO codeset (codeset ,codevalue ,  columnn,  systeme) VALUES ('test3', 3,      'col3',  'sys1');
INSERT INTO codeset (codeset ,codevalue ,  columnn,  systeme) VALUES ('test3', 4,      'col4',  'sys1');
INSERT INTO codeset (codeset ,codevalue ,  columnn,  systeme) VALUES ('test3', 5,      'col5',  'sys1');
INSERT INTO codeset (codeset ,             columnn,  systeme) VALUES ('test4',         'col6',  'sys1');
INSERT INTO codeset (codeset ,codevalue ,  columnn,  systeme) VALUES ('test5', 6,      'col7',  'sys2');
INSERT INTO codeset (codeset ,codevalue ,  columnn,  systeme) VALUES ('test5', 7,      'col8',  'sys2');
```

And the query:

```
SELECT a.codeset, a.codevalue, b.columnn,b.systeme
FROM
        codeset a
OUTER JOIN
        codeset b ON a.codeset = b.codeset
ORDER BY a.codeset, a.codevalue
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH DATA AS (SELECT
    *
FROM (
    VALUES ('test2', 2,      'col2',  'sys1'),
      ('test3', 3,      'col3',  'sys1'), 
      ('test3', 4,      'col4',  'sys1'),
      ('test3', 5,      'col5',  'sys1'),
      ('test4',  0,       'col6',  'sys1'),
      ('test5', 6,      'col7',  'sys2'),
      ('test5', 7,      'col8',  'sys2')
) AS t(codeset ,codevalue , columnn_name, systeme)
)

select * from data 
union all
select a.* from data a
cross JOIN data b
where a.codeset = 'test3'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `VALUES (...),(...)` is not valid syntax in Oracle and neither is `WITH (...) AS table_alias (column_aliases...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it manually you can just use an insert statement for each row you want to add, eg:

```
INSERT INTO table (codeset, codevalue, column, system ) VALUES ('test3', 3, 'col2', 'sys1' );
```